# express js apps.local variable and view output

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

im about to finish an application using node.js and express, although im quite new with them.

Here is my situation, in my app.js i declared a variable by `app.locals.webLang` and initialized it with "EN". with this variable i render the language text of my page whose data is retrieved from a json file that i have saved in my file directory. This variable can only be change if the user clicks on a dropdown menu and selects another language. So if we have one user that clicks, lets say, french, a function will be called to change this webLang variable to "FR" and afterthat i call location.reload() to refresh the page and it will result with the text in french instead of english because of the json data that has all the text saved in french also.

Now my question is, if another user accesses my website after the first user changed the language to french, will that second user retrieve the page in french or will the server send him a copy of the application that starts in english?

my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.locals.webLang = "EN";

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/web_text.json',function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/web_text.json');
});
app.post('/change', (req, res) => {
  const newVar = req.body.global;
  app.locals.webLang = newVar;
  res.json({
    success: true
  });
});


app.use('/', index);

module.exports = app;
```

client-side javascript file (public/javascripts/.js file):

```
$(document).on('click', '#footer .dropdown-menu li', function(){

    var language = $(this).attr('data-lang');

    fetch('/change', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({global: language})
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload()
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    }, 500);
});
```

index ejs file that contains dropdown:
(removed irrelevant elements)

```
<html lang=<%= webLang %>>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="dropup bth-group">
       <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="Language_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span>Language</span> <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Language_dropdown">
            <li data-lang="EN">English&nbsp;<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span></li>
           <li data-lang="ES">Espa&ntilde;ol&nbsp;<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span></li>
           <li data-lang="FR">Fran&ccedil;ais&nbsp;<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></span></li>
           <li data-lang="IT">Italiano&nbsp;<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"></span></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

route index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var wt = require('../web_text.json');
var counter = 0;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  for(var i = 0; i < wt.length;i++){
      if(req.app.locals.webLang == wt[i].lang){
          counter = i;
          break;
      }
  }
  res.render('index', { web_text: wt[counter].text });
});

module.exports = router;
```

json data file:

```
[
    {
        "lang": "EN",
        "text":{
        }
    },
    {
        "lang": "ES",
        "text":{
        }
    },
    {
        "lang": "FR",
        "text":{
        }
    },
    {
        "lang": "IT",
        "text":{
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Its a bit hard to help when you don't provide some of your code to give a bit of context and visual representation of where you put the variable

Comment: my bad, edited and added revelant code

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use `res.render()`? Instead of just sending the file as you are currently.

Comment: can you elaborate? like i said, im fairly new with node and express so i dont know exactly if my approaches to my goal are the correct ones

Answer (score 2):

Ejs is a templating engine and should be used as one, you set the view path yet you don't use it.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

is essentially saying "Hey, go into the "/views" folder and in there will be all my .ejs files that I'll be rendering!". Since that's the case, your ejs files **should** be in that directory. Once you're sure of that, you can proceed.

A benefit is that you can "render" files, hence being able to pass variables from your server to the file you'll be sending on the client's end. For example, say I have an ejs file called `home.ejs`. I could render the file like this:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let randomVariable = "This is random";
    res.render("home", {variable: randomVariable});
});
```

Notice how I can reference the `home.ejs` file by just using its name. I can *also* pass in a variable to the file. In this case I passed the `randomVariable` as a value in an object. If I wanted the title of `home.ejs` to have that variable as the title, I could do this:

**home.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> <%= variable %> </title>
</head>
</html>
```

### Why is this important?

Instead of declaring the language for that page outside and making it global, you could just pass it directly to the page.

```
app.get("/index", (req, res) => {
    lang = "EN"
    res.render("index", {language: lang})
});
```

And then when a user requests a different language you can just make the drop-down menu be links to the same page but with a different language. For example:

```
<li><a href="/index/FR">French</a></li>
<li><a href="/index/IT">Italiano</a></li>
```

And then handle the request on the server.

```
app.get("/index/:lang", (req, res) => {
    let lang = req.params.lang;
    res.render("index", {lang: lang})
});
```

And index.ejs would look like:

```
<html lang=<%= lang %>>
```

Notice how I can do `:lang` in the url, it just means it will accept anything that comes after `/index/`

If its confusing in any way, let me know.

Comment: i understood everything you wrote, know, the way im rendering the text from my json data is via de route file... i edited my question and added the code so you can take a look! if i were to implement your code, i will a bring it all together?

Comment: *how can i bring it all together?**

Comment: Wright!! your idea worked like a charm although a couple of questions arised involving the app.js file and the route index.js file! i will appreciate if we could move this conversation to a chat so you orient and answer those doubts!! thank a lot

Comment: @cjlogrono11 Sorry, just seeing this now, sure I'll have time in about an hour or 3